# Python - How do i solve UTF8 issues with JSON on Heroku?

Tags: python, json, utf

I have a .txt filled with a list of dictionaries, and in there are some file names, some containing ä ö ü. Im trying to load it with this code:

```
with open('res/mp3s_stats.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
     data = json.load(f)
```

but i get this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\laure\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\laure\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\laure\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 6184: invalid continuation byte
```

What can i do to solve this? I already use encoding="utf-8" on every time i write or read to this file :/

Comment: When you open the file you don't specify an encoding, so Python uses the default; evidently the default is different on your machine vs heroku.  I would be inclined to specify 'utf-8' as the encoding (because it can encode any unicode character) and ensure that the json file is saved as UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My gut feeling says your txt file isn't actually UTF-8 encoded. (`0XE4` is a valid ISO-8859-15 character (ä), but not a valid UTF-8 character.)

Comment: Oh, that is a thing i had not considered, when saving the file in notepad i changed the encoding and it worked, thanks!